# Is there an API or web service for Copy-SPSite?

Tags: powershell, api, wsdl

What API endpoint is called for the command `Copy-SPSite`? Also, is there a WSDL web service for this command, like there is the `ExportWeb` service in `Sites.asmx` relating to the command `Export-SPWeb`?

Comment: What version of SharePoint? If SPO, no.

Comment: Checked on-prem, the only thing that calls the copy API is the Copy-SPSite and the upgrade eval site process (v14.5 -> 15).